# An attribute argument must be an array expression of an atttribute parameter type

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, nunit

I am making a unittest using the Nunit framework, and I am using the `Combinatorial` attribute, allowing me to provide argument data.
I want to provide an int array that is within a range of `1-10` as argument data.
The test is written as follows:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    [Combinatorial]
    public void Test1(
        [Values(Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToArray())] int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

However, the `Values` attribute gives me the following error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

How do I create this constant int array, without having to type out all the individual numbers?

Comment: You can't. That's not how constants work. You probably want [`[TestCaseSource]`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcasesource.html).

Comment: Thanks! Since I wanted to use multiple values, using the `Combinatorial` attribute, I solved it with [`[ValueSource]`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/valuesource.html): `[ValueSource("array")] int x`, with `public static int[] array = Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToArray();`